# How to manage azure key vault values for different environment

Tags: c#, azure-keyvault

I have multiple environments where my application will be deployed and my application is not deployed on Azure. I am taking an initiative to store secrets in azure key vaults. Whenever the application will be deployed on each environment. I will.need to change the connection string of my application. Does azure key vault facilitate us to deal with this scenario.
or I need to set different key vault for each environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to create separation between the different environments and have separate Azure Key Vault instances for each one, each one with separate access credentials. In this way you have a really secure setup, so even if one environment is hacked, they can't get all the secrets for the other ones.